# Get all video qualities from a block of text using a regex

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I want to get all video qualitys from string. My string:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2750000
2500/prog_index.m3u8?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
```

And my PHP code:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\/prog_index.m3u8/mis", $serviceurlget, $C);
print_r($C);
```

Returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128/prog_index.m3u8
            [1] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500/prog_index.m3u8
            [2] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750/prog_index.m3u8
            [3] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000/prog_index.m3u8
            [4] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500/prog_index.m3u8
            [5] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2750000
2500/prog_index.m3u8
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => #EXTM3U
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=350000
128
            [1] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=750000
500
            [2] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1000000
750
            [3] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1250000
1000
            [4] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=1750000
1500
            [5] => ?key=49bfee85b05d117a2906368428094e94
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:PROGRAM-ID=1,BANDWIDTH=2750000
2500
        )

)
```

But I don't want this result. I want it to return `128 500 750 1000 1500 2500`. How can I do it? I tried `explode()` function. But it didn't work. I think there is a mistake with my regex code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `m` and `s` modifiers from the `preg_match_all()` statement. These modifiers affect how the pattern matches the subject string, and are not always required:

- **`m` modifier changes the meaning of the line anchors (`^` and `$`)** from "match at the beginning/end of the *string*" to "match at the beginning/end of each *line*". If there are no newline characters in the subject string, or no occurrences of line anchors in the regex pattern, this modifier is useless.
- **`s` modifier changes the meaning of the dot meta-character (`.`)** from "match everything except newline characters" to "match everything *including* newline characters". This allows you to treat the whole string as a single line.

See the [PHP manual documentation on *Pattern Modifiers*](http://php.net//manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for more information.

---

Your code should be:

```
preg_match_all("/(.*?)\/prog_index\.m3u8/i", $serviceurlget, $C);
print_r($C[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 128
    [1] => 500
    [2] => 750
    [3] => 1000
    [4] => 1500
    [5] => 2500
)
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/163519)

Comment: Answer with the perfect amount of detail, and beautifully formatted. :) +1