# Replace a particular content in a string using regex php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string like

> some text for test and need to replace by regex using php
>   we have extra sentence too

I need to replace the sentence before the word `regex`

I need a result of

> using php
>   we have extra sentence too

Replace `some text for test and need to replace by regex` by `""`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PHP can use `\K`**

Use this simple regex:

```
(?s)^.*?regex\K.*
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/gN6bG7).

- The `(?s)` allows the dot to match across several lines.
- `^` asserts that we are at the beginning of the string.
- `.*?regex` lazily matches everything up to `regex`
- `\K` tells the engine to "Keep" everything it has matched so far out of the returned match (drop it)
- `.*` matches everything else. This is the returned match.

In PHP, no need to replace. As the output of this [php demo](https://ideone.com/6LZNZk) shows, you can just match:

```
$mystring = "some text for test and need to replace by regex using php.
We have another sentence";
$regex = '~(?s)^.*?regex\K.*~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
```

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for this. You can use [**substr()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [**strpos()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
$str = substr($str, strpos($str, 'regex') + 6);
```

[**See demo**](http://codepad.org/JEzk7J3K)

Answer (score 0):

The below regex will match only the characters which are just after to the string `regex`,

```
/(?<=regex\s)(.*)/s
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qT0hC9)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$mystring = "some text for test and need to replace by regex using php.
We have another sentence";
$regex = '~(?s)(?<=regex\s)(.*)~';
if (preg_match($regex, $mystring, $m)) {
    $yourmatch = $m[0]; 
    echo $yourmatch;
    }
?>
```

**Output:**

```
using php.
We have another sentence
```

**Explanation:**

```
(?s)              #  Allows . to match anything(including newlines)
(?<=regex\s)(.*)  #  Positive lookbehind is used. It matches anything after the string regex followed by a space.
```

Comment: You don't need to add `s` and `m` modifiers into every regex. They [do different things](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24249564/1438393). Here you only need the `s` modifier :)